# Sharepoint Timer job creates list item but doesnot fire item event handlers

Tags: sharepoint, event-handling

I have a timer job which adds an item to the SP List.
I have bound one Item Added list item event handler to the list.
The event handler gets fired when an item manually added to the List by SharePoint front end.

But it is not triggered when the list item is created within the timer job.

Please provide any solution/workaround for this.

Comment: Finally,

I figured it out. I had attached the debugger to w3wp.exe.

Event handler runs under Timer Service Process. So when I attached the debugger to OwsTimer, it worked like a charm :)

Thanks to all...

Comment: John - put your comment in as an answer then you can mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out. I had attached the debugger to w3wp.exe.

Event handler runs under Timer Service Process. 
So when I attached the debugger to OwsTimer, it worked like a charm :)

Thanks to all... –